# Shimano GRX Left 2X lever with dropper post

Tags: shimano

Has anyone run a dropper post with the GRX 2X left lever? Intuition tells me it won't work since it'll click into the next "gear" and get stuck there, without being able to return.

I can get by for now with a solid post, but would like to know if a dropper has a future with my current GRX 2X left lever.

Comment: I think you'll have to get an external lever, e.g., https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/collections/dropper-levers/products/remote-drop-bar

Comment: Wait, are you runny a 2x drivetrain or 1x?

Comment: I think you need to clarify whether you want to use a 2x lever as a dropper lever, or whether you want to add a dropper lever ontop of the 2x lever.

Comment: I have seen some mods where people basically modify the ratcheting mechanism (search the internet for something like "shimano left lever dropper mod"). They remove or dremel away some of the teeth or pawls so that the shifter won't click into the gear positions any more and returns instead when you release it. Obviously, this voids any warranties and I haven't tried it, so I'm not posting an answer unless somebody really thinks that this comment is helpful ;-)

Comment: @anderas That was going to be my answer, but you got here first! You can either remove the pawl entirely, or just the return spring I believe.

Comment: @MaplePanda thank you! I slightly expanded it and posted it as an answer.

Comment: @abdnChap I am running a 1X drivetrain. Currently, I have a rigid seatpost, but if I want to run a dropper I want to know what my options are, either with a hack or part swap. I do not want to add a dropper lever to my 2X. I will either do what anderas says, or try to swap my 2X with the Shimano dropper-specific lever (ST-RX810-LA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using a 1x drivetrain and have, for some reason, a 2x left shifter (maybe after changing the chainset to 1x). If that assumption is false, you need to add a dropper lever or you won't be able to shift your gears - there are some that are designed specifically to fit near the stem on the handlebars of gravel bikes.

**If you want to use your existing shifter to operate a dropper,** the main problem  is the indexed gear shift mechanism that keeps the cable at a specific length/tension for each gear.

**A simple bodge** using your current shifter would be to simply try to use the lever as-is. Then, you would have to "shift" to the position of the largest cog, operate the dropper and then shift "back down" when the dropper is in your desired position.

The next step up would be to **irreversibly** modify your shifter. This involves taking apart the delicate mechanisms so *don't do this if value any kind of warranty or you do not feel comfortable handling small small springs, ratcheting mechanisms and whatever else you may encounter in the insides of the shifter!*

You basically remove the hoods and take apart the shifter until you see the indexing mechanism, i.e. some toothed parts and pawls that 'click' into them when operating the shifter. Once you have identified the actual parts that keep the cable under tension when in the  large gear, you have to grind/hacksaw away these teeth or remove the pawls. Then reassemble the shifter, taking special care of any springs inside the mechanism. As a bonus, you can remove the now-useless downshift lever if it bothers you.

The details vary with each shifter and I have not done that myself. So I sadly cannot provide any images, but searching the internet for something like "shimano left lever dropper mod" will give you an idea of what to expect.

Answer (score 2):

No, but provided you are running a 1x setup, you can use the [Shimano GRX ST-RX810-LA](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-11-speed/ST-RX810-LA.html) left hand lever, which is specifically designed to control a dropper post

Comment: My lever is still in box, any suggestion on marketplaces where a trade might take place?

Comment: I'm not sure what part of the world you're in but your local bike shops/clubs might be a good start, otherwise there's always eBay...